# Count clubbed for different date ranges - Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, date, count, query-optimization

I have following tables and data:

T_USER

```
ID         | COUNTRY_NAME
---------------------------
101         FRANCE
102         GERMANY
103         ITALY
104         FRANCE
105         ITALY
106         FRANCE
107         GERMANY
108         ITALY
109         FRANCE
110         ITALY
```

T_LOG_ACCESS

```
ID          |  APPLICATION  |   ACCESS_DATE
-------------------------------------------

101               Portal-M      10/6/2017 
102               Portal-H      10/6/2017
103               Portal-E      10/6/2017
104               Portal-E      10/6/2017
101               Portal-M      10/6/2017
102               Portal-E      10/6/2017
103               Portal-E      10/6/2017
104               Portal-E      10/6/2017
105               Portal-M      10/6/2017
106               Portal-E      10/6/2017
107               Portal-E      10/6/2017
108               Portal-E      10/6/2017
104               Portal-E      10/6/2017
105               Portal-E      10/6/2017
106               Portal-E      10/6/2017
101               Portal-M      11/6/2017
102               Portal-H      11/6/2017
102               Portal-E      11/6/2017
104               Portal-E      11/6/2017
105               Portal-M      11/6/2017
105               Portal-E      11/6/2017
107               Portal-E      11/6/2017
107               Portal-E      11/6/2017
108               Portal-E      11/6/2017
```

T_ROLES

```
USER      |    ROLE
--------------------

101         M_ACT
101         E_ACT
102         H_ACT
102         E_ACT
103         E_ACT
104         E_ACT
105         M_ACT
105         E_ACT
106         E_ACT
107         E_ACT
108         E_ACT
109         E_ACT
110         M_ACT
110         E_ACT
```

I am trying to take distinct count of only those users (group by country) who accessed the portal in both months, i.e. those who accessed in October and again accessed in November.

I am trying with the following query, but due to a large amount of actual data, the query is taking whopping 15 minutes to execute:

```
select
    COUNTRY_NAME,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-M' and SUB2.role='M_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END)Manager_Count, 
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-H' and SUB2.role='H_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END)HR_Count, 
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-H' and SUB2.role='E_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END) Employee_COUNT 
from
    T_USER MAIN
    INNER JOIN T_LOG_ACCESS SUB1 
        ON MAIN.id=SUB1.id 
        AND TO_DATE(to_char(SUB1.access_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') between 
    --Report 1st Time Period:
    TO_DATE('20171101','YYYYMMDD')and TO_DATE('20171130','YYYYMMDD')
    INNER JOIN T_ROLES SUB2 
        ON MAIN.id=SUB2.user
           AND SUB2.user in 
                (SELECT DISTINCT SUB7.id 
                 from T_LOG_ACCESS SUB7, 
                      T_ROLES SUB8 
                 where SUB7.APPLICATION=SUB1.APPLICATION 
                 AND SUB8.role=SUB2.role 
                 AND TO_DATE(to_char(SUB7.access_date,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') between
    --Report 2nd Time Period:
                TO_DATE('20171001','YYYYMMDD')and TO_DATE('20171031','YYYYMMDD') )
 group by COUNTRY_NAME;
```

Is there any way to make this query faster? Please help.

Comment: First of all remove that nasty to_date(to_char(...)) around date column, you do not need it. Column access_date is already date type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Goran. Done.

Comment: You do not need distinct in the subquery (select distinct sub7.id ...) - I would also change this to exists condition and compare execution plans. Your naming standards are making it hard to follow what you are trying to do (giving the same alias with different number to all tables - sub1, sub2, sub3...).

Answer (score 0):

Giving query tuning advice without seeing an explain plan or knowing the data volume and skew is a mug's game. But here goes.

There are several obvious problems with your code.

1. There is no need to cast the dates back and forth
2. The DISTINCT in the subquery is superfluous: the IN operator doesn't care how many hits there are.
3. The biggest problem is that the nested query has no join condition between `T_LOG_ACCESS SUB7` and `T_ROLES SUB8` so the query will be a Cartesian product which you then reduce with the DISTINCT. That's a lot of crunch wasted right there.

Given some assumptions about your data volume and skew this *might* be faster:

```
with SUB1 as (
     select id
            , application
     from T_LOG_ACCESS
     where access_date >= date '2017-11-01'
     and access_date <= date '2017-11-30'
     )
   , SUB7 as (
     select id
            , application
     from T_LOG_ACCESS
     where access_date >= date '2017-01-01'
     and access_date <= date '2017-01-31'
     )
select
    COUNTRY_NAME,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-M' and SUB2.role='M_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END) Manager_Count, 
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-H' and SUB2.role='H_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END) HR_Count, 
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SUB1.APPLICATION='Portal-H' and SUB2.role='E_ACT' THEN SUB1.id END) Employee_COUNT 
from 
    T_USER MAIN
    INNER JOIN T_LOG_ACCESS SUB1 
        ON MAIN.id=SUB1.id 
    INNER JOIN T_ROLES SUB2 
        ON MAIN.id=SUB2.user    
where SUB2.user in 
                (SELECT SUB7.id 
                 from SUB7
                 where SUB7.APPLICATION=SUB1.APPLICATION )
group by COUNTRY_NAME;
```

---

Note: I have retained you table aliases to make this more transparent to you, even though I agree with @GoranStefanović that these are horrible and make your query harder to understand.